# rxjava PublishSubject second time not subscribe

Tags: java, rx-java2

```
private static PublishSubject<UserBean> mPublishSubject;
private static AtomicBoolean mRefreshing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private static Observable<UserBean> mTokenObservable;

public Observable<UserBean> getNetTokenLocked() {
    if (mRefreshing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "first    request");
        mTokenObservable.subscribe(mPublishSubject);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "else  wait back");
    }
    return mPublishSubject;                         //second didn't return  
}
```

return mPublishSubject;  <-   I want to be able to give me the previous data for the second time

Comment: Check Replay or Behavior subjects: [ReplaySubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/ReplaySubject.html), [Behavior Subject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Publish Subject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html) emits all the subsequent items of the source Observable at the time of subscription. If you want to emit all the items of the source Observable, regardless of when the subscriber subscribes, use Replay Subject.

```
PublishSubject<Integer> source = PublishSubject.create();

// It will get 1, 2, 3, 4 and onComplete
source.subscribe(getFirstObserver()); 

source.onNext(1);
source.onNext(2);
source.onNext(3);

// It will get 4 and onComplete for second observer also.
source.subscribe(getSecondObserver());

source.onNext(4);
source.onComplete();
```

Comment: one example,   five http request，they all returned  ，five request  token have expired，then five request  use refresh token ， that is low efficiency，i want use only one  refresh token，that  return  OK   ，then five http request   use new token 。    Only  Rxjava

Comment: The best approach that is recommended, is to use the Authenticator interface that is provided by OkHttp3 that is basically an interface that is triggered every time you get a 401 response (UNAUTHORIZED).
The Authenticator interface overrides authenticate method that has a return type of Request instead of Response like the Interceptor interface, which in a way is telling you when criteria is meat 401 response (UNAUTHORIZED)then make another request with new headers.